# Check a cell that has a negative value

Tags: vba

I would like  to know how to check a cell that contains a negative value and apply some changes.

I started with this code but I got  an error in this  statement `If (ActiveSheet.Cells(a, 37).Value)< 0`

Here is my code :

```
dim a as integer
Dim MaPlage As Range`

For a = 2 To ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set MaPlage = Range("A:AP").Rows(a)
    If (ActiveSheet.Cells(a, 37).Value) < 0  Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(a, 31).Interior.Color = vbYellow           
        ActiveSheet.Cells(a, 14).Interior.Color = vbYellow`
    End If
Next a
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Type mismatch error 13

Comment: What value of `a` at the point of error?

Comment: And, what is actually in that cell?  If it's an error value like `#N/A` or '#NAME!` etc., that would raise a Mismatch error.

Comment: a is the number of line it starts from a= 2

Comment: i have  - 8 in (5,37)

Comment: The value within the cell is "8 in (5,37")?

Comment: it works i just replaced .value by .text     :) thanks for ur help

Comment: `(ActiveSheet.Cells(a, 37).Text) < 0 Then`

Comment: I still have no idea what you're actually describing, but I suspect that @steenbergh's answer below is what you will need.

Comment: its doesn't work with .value because i use a formula inside the (5,37) to get -8 or 8

Comment: This is a terrible question.

Comment: What is "(5,37)"?  Are you talking about a cell reference?  Your question would benefit greatly from better description, including the error message, and example of the data which is causing the failure, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Type Mismatch` means you're checking an integer (the `< 0` part of your `if`-statement) with a text value. You need to check if the tested value is numeric, using the `IsNumeric()` function: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/isnumeric.php

Your code would become:

```
dim a as integer
Dim MaPlage As Range

For a = 2 To ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set MaPlage = Range("A:AP").Rows(a)
    If IsNumeric(ActiveSheet.Cells(a, 37).Value) and (ActiveSheet.Cells(a, 37).Value) < 0  Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(a, 31).Interior.Color = vbYellow           
        ActiveSheet.Cells(a, 14).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If
Next a
```

Comment: even when i need to use two conditions : `If (ActiveSheet.Cells(a, 37).Text) < 0 And (ActiveSheet.Cells(a, 38).Text) Then`